# what machine learning algorithm is used while creating a text classifier model using createML?

Tags: swift, createml

I'm creating a text classification model for sentiment analysis, I would like to know what machine learning algorithm is used by createML here?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the algorithm used by the classifier or specify the language which you would like to classify in the parameters of the initializer. See the developer documentation in Xcode under CreateML > MLTextClassifier > MLTextClassifier.ModelParameters

init(validation: MLTextClassifier.ModelParameters.ValidationData, algorithm: MLTextClassifier.ModelAlgorithmType, language: NLLanguage?)

under the parameter algorithm set the algorithm you would like to use.

In developer documentation under the enum MLTextClassifier.ModelAlgorithmType you will find what is available. For example: case crf(revision: Int?) is a conditional random field model algorithm.